# passing get request from bootstrap button

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, get

How do I trigger a get request from a bootstrap button? I have the following code:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="/signup" id="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
```

and would like this button to perform a get request with the following value **"signup"**

I am using a MEAN stack and the routes are set up so when the app is accessed with the get value /signup it goes to the signup page. But I am not able to get the bootstrap 3 button to post a get a request.

Comment: Could you post the HTML for the entire form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your form you will need the following two attributes:

1. Action = "{URL TO SEND THE FORM TO}"
2. Method = "{GET or POST}"

For a signup with a username and password you should really think about doing a POST request so the form element should look like (for a POST request):

```
<form action="/signup" method="POST" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
```

or for a get request:

```
<form action="/signup" method="GET" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
```